# How to disable JerseyClient request logging in runtime?

Tags: java, jersey-client

How to disable JerseyClient request logging in runtime?

I've got code like that:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(new LoggingFeature(LOGGER, level.INFO, null, null))
```

I can't figure out how to disable logging in runtime? Maybe there is some config params to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to change the logging level, just change `Level.INFO` with `Level.WARNING` or higher. (more about [java.util.logging.Level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html)).

Or comment second line (if you don't set logger, the client will not be able to log).